# How to parse/use this JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable with the following in my code:

```
{
"Rows":
    [
        {
            "New":1,
            "CachedNumberType":0,
            "Date":1327479615921,
            "Type":2,
            "Number":"123456",
            "Duration":1
        }
    ]
}
```

I think it's JSON, how do I parse it? (E.g., with json2.js?) Or how do I use it in my JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that when you try `JSON.parse` on the variable containing the "JSON" that it says it can't parse it. Could it be that it's already deserialized? Or maybe it was never JSON at all? For instance, what you quoted, in JavaScript source, is an object literal containing an array literal containing another object literal; no JSON in sight.

If you do `console.log(x.Rows[0].Date);`, where `x` is the variable you were trying to pass to JSON.parse, do you see the date value?

A lot of people confuse JSON and JavaScript literal syntax, because JSON is a textual format derived from JavaScript literal syntax. I suspect that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 3):

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: I have an Object which contains the string... How will i convert that to JSON string?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: Just pass the object that holds the json string as the argument to `JSON.parse`

Comment: it is saying unable to parse JSON string. :(

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: If you have that string assigned to a variable, please make sure all the quotes have been escaped or it will end the json string prematurely.

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: Then are you sure it's a JSON string? Could it be that it's *already* deserialized? Or may be it was never JSON at all? (For instance, what you quoted, in JavaScript source, is an object literal containing an array literal containing another object literal; no JSON in sight.) What happens if you do `console.log(x.Rows[0].Date);`, where `x` is the variable you were trying to pass to `JSON.parse`. (If you don't know `console.log`, use `alert` instead.)

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: Some background on how you're receiving that 'Json string' would be helpful. Is it a response sent by a third party API you are consuming? Is it the response to an AJAX request to your own server side script?

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I got the result without parsing only :D. Directly from the object i printed the values. :D